# redirect after a fetch post call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, fetch

I am creating an social login page with an Access Management (AM) server.
When the user clicks on the login button then I make a `fetch()` `HTTP` `POST` call to the AM server. The AM server generates an `HTTP 301` redirect response with auth cookies to the social login page. I need to follow this redirect response somehow and show the new content in the web browser.

UI: ReactJS

Request:

```
POST /api/auth/socialauth/initiate HTTP/1.1
Host    example.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0)
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
origin  http://web.example.com:8080
Referer http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/login
Cookie  authId=...; NTID=...
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fam.example.com%3A8083%2Fopenam%2Foauth2c%2FOAuthProxy.jsp&response_type=code&state=qtrwtidnwdpbft4ctj2e9mv3mjkifqo
```

React code:

```
initiateSocialLogin() {
    var url = "/api/auth/socialauth/initiate";

    fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })
        .then(response => {
            // HTTP 301 response
            // HOW CAN I FOLLOW THE HTTP REDIRECT RESPONSE?
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.info(err + " url: " + url);
        });
}
```

How I can follow the redirect response and show the new content in the web browser?

Comment: you could have `fetch` automatically redirect, change `fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })` to `fetch(url, { method: 'POST', redirect: 'follow' })`

Comment: Plese have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[Request.redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect) could be `"follow"`, `"error"` or `"manual"`.

> If it is "follow", fetch() API follows the redirect response (HTTP
>   status code = 301,302,303,307,308).
>
> If it is "error", fetch() API treats the redirect response as an
>   error.
>
> If it is "manual", fetch() API doesn't follow the redirect and returns
>   an opaque-redirect filtered response which wraps the redirect
>   response.

Since you want to redirect after a fetch  just use it as

```
fetch(url, { method: 'POST', redirect: 'follow'})
    .then(response => {
        // HTTP 301 response
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.info(err + " url: " + url);
    });
```

Comment: The problem with redirect: 'follow' is that i need to show the page in the browser. So I need somehow to redirect the browser and show the new content.

Comment: the above code with cors set does not redirect automatically. But I do see the new URL in Network tab in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build). Any idea why is the browser not rendering it.

Comment: How to achieve the same using axios

Comment: - The problem with redirect: 'follow' is that i need to show the page in the browser.  
In this case I think using `manual` and then setting the `location.href` or even `window.open` using the [Location header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) of the returned response

Comment: is it possible to get the redirected url when using `manual`?

Comment: @BenKoshy no it is not. @Luke T O'Brien `manual` returns an opaque response for service workers to replay responses. it is a zero byte, inaccessible, basically unusable response. Not what you are looking for. `error` may be more useful

Comment: `error` is also useless because it only throws an error, but give no access to the redirect response

Comment: This doesn't work at all, no redirect is performed. You can't even access the `location` header to manually redirect! Can't believe how difficult following a 302 is!

Answer (score 54):

Have a look at properties [url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url) [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected) of Response object:
Doc says that this is

> "Experimental. Expect behavior to change in the future"
>
> The url read-only property of the Response interface contains the URL
>   of the response. The value of the url property will be the final URL
>   obtained after any redirects.

In my experiments, this 'url' property was exactly the same as the value of Location header in Chrome (Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) Network console.

The code to deal with redirecting link my look like this:

```
   fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })
    .then(response => {
        // HTTP 301 response
        // HOW CAN I FOLLOW THE HTTP REDIRECT RESPONSE?
        if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.info(err + " url: " + url);
    });
```

I tested it working with react.js same-origin script with fetch AJAX call facing redirects 302 from server.

**P.S.** In SPA apps, redirect responses are unlikely, maybe this is the reason why ajax vendors apply little attention to this functionality.
See also these discussions:
[here](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/763)
[here](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/601)

Comment: doesn't seem to load the response, my api is providing some flash messaging after the post is evaluated.

Comment: I've followed this approach, but bear in mind that this makes 2 separate requests to `response.url`. Just look at the network tab.

Comment: Why would it make two requests?

Comment: @stevemoretz: one during the fetch for your post request and one for the actual redirect to go to the page.

Comment: Oh you counted the `window.location.href` part cool!

Comment: Technically, every redirect for most HTTP clients, in this case the browser HTTP client, are more than one request under the hood. This just makes it explicit.

Answer (score 37):

It is not possible to follow a redirect to a new HTML page with javascript.

```js
fetch(url, { method: 'POST', redirect: "follow" });
```

will simply perform another request to the redirected location which will be returned as data and not rendered by the browser. You might expect to be able to use `{ redirect : "manual" }`, get the redirected location from the response and navigate to the page with Javascript, but unfortunately the redirected location is not returned, see https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/763.

Comment: This more like deserves to be the answer, but you didn't include a solution.

Comment: @janat08 I don't think there is a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: So there's no way to redirect ever in any case using Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar issue and I believe that the answer for fetch inside React is the same as it is for ajax inside JQuery - if you are able to detect that the response is a redirect, then update the window.location.href with the response.url

See for example: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Note that 'if you are able to detect that the response is a redirect' might be the tricky part. Fetch responses *may* contain a 'redirected' flag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) but I've found that is not the case in Chrome. I also find in Chrome I get a 200 status response rather than a redirect status - but that could be something with our SSO implementation. If you are using a fetch polyfill with IE then you'll need to check whether response.url is included or not.

Comment: As of Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) --> it does return a "redirected" flag and a url and 200 status
And inspite of setting the "redirect" to "follow" --> it does not redirect itself and I need to use window.location

Comment: window.location will make a new requests, giving a total of 2 @j10. idk what's the proper approach, but none of the answers here is correct

Comment: Chrome now follows the redirect  by default https://chromestatus.com/feature/4614142321229824

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this scenario was sent the url I want to be redirected as a parameter and then receiving it in body response, instead of using redirect from server

Answer (score 2):

To make redirect work on fetch, this is how I do:

```
fetch(url, {redirect:'manual'})
.then(response => {
  if (response.type == "opaqueredirect"){  
  // To make sure the fetch is with redirect response return.  
    window.location.replace('.../redirectURL/'); // create one and only one request
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

Another way to do it is as follows. However, this method would create two requests to the redirected url. The first request won't change the content. Only would the second request do.

```
fetch(url, {redirect:'follow'}) // 'follow' creates the first request
.then(response => {
  if (response.redirected) {
    window.location.replace(response.url); 
  // creates the second request, and change the content
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

> https://javascript.info/fetch-api#redirect

Answer (score 0):

I tried using fetch to redirect to the url but this method didn't work, so I ended up using a different method to get the redirect to work. Inside your react component follow the following steps:

- Step 1: create a state variable:

```
const [_id,setID]=useState('')
```

- Step 2: create a method that updates the state:

```
function uidValue(event) {
        const endpoint = '/api/users/'+ event.target.value // this will be your url, so set it right.
        setID(endpoint)
    }
```

- Step 3: in the return section of your component add an `onChange` listener to the username(id in my case):

```
<input id="uid" type="text" name=":_id" placeholder=":_id" onChange={uidValue} />
```

- Step 4: make sure all your inputs are inside a form, and add an `action` attribute to the `form` tag that sets the URL you want it to navigate to using your state:

```
<form  action={_id} id="login info" method="post" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "redirected" property inside the incoming data, then manually redirect(you need to send a 302 status code from the server first):

```
  await fetch('http://localhost:3333/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: data,
  })
    .then(data => data.redirected && (document.location.href = '/foro'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Fetch is not able to get the redirect URL, but XMLHttpRequest can.

if you want to get the redirect URL, you can try this code:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "/api/auth/socialauth/initiate");

xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseUR);
    this.abort();
  }
};
```