# React Login form throws error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express

Hi I am making a full stack login form. The error I am receiving is ": Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" see full log at the bottom.

All i want to do is create a login form that will redirect me to the home page in which I can then start work upon the jwt tokens.

Any idea why this is happening?
Any suggestions on how to get this form fully working?

Thanks for all your help :)

```
app.post("/auth", function(req, response) {
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err + "initial connection");
      console.log(config.server);
    } else {
      try {
        var request = new sql.Request();

        var body = req.body;

        //console.log(body);

        var email = body.email;
        var password = body.password;

        console.log(email, password);

        try {
          request.input("email", sql.VarChar, email);
          request.input("password", sql.VarChar, password);
          request.query(
            "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = 'email' AND password = 'password'",

            function(error, results, fields) {
              if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.email = email;
                response.redirect("/home");
              } else {
                response.send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
              }
              response.end();
            }
          );

          response.send("Please enter email and Password!");
          response.end();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          response.status(400);
          response.send(e);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.status(400);
        response.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Login class

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { email: "", password: "" };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

      fetch("/auth", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);
    return (
      <div>
        <Formik
          class="form-signin"
          action="auth"
          method="POST"
          initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Logging in", values);
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
              .email()
              .required("Required")
              .matches(
                /(?=.*codestone)/,
                "This is not a Codestone email address."
              ),

            password: Yup.string()
              .required("No password provided.")
              .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
              .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
          })}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit
            } = props;

            return (
              <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                class="form-signin"
                action="auth"
                method="POST"
              >
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <h2>Login </h2>
                  <div className="help">
                    <Popup trigger={<Link> Help?</Link>} className="center">
                      <div>
                        Enter Codestone Email address and Password connected to
                        the account.
                      </div>
                    </Popup>
                  </div>

                  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>

                  <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    value1={values.email}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onInput={handleChange}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                  )}
                  <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
                  <input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                    value2={values.password}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onInput={handleChange}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password} </div>
                  )}

                  <button class="button" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                    Login
                  </button>
                  <p>
                    <Link to="/login"> Login Page </Link>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <Link to="/reset"> Reset Password </Link>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Error

```
undefined undefined
[0] _http_outgoing.js:535
[0]     throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
[0]     ^
[0]
[0] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\server.js:183:26
[0]     at C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:395:9
[0]     at Request.userCallback (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:471:15)
[0]     at Request.callback (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:56:14)
[0]     at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2402:20)
[0]     at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1274:15)
[0]     at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Henry Peters\Desktop\Vault\Newfolder(3)\Codestone-Desk-branch1\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1067:14) {
[0]   code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

Update after suggested changes. This still does not redirect user to the hpome page or even show any signs of logging in in user. No errors are displayed in console or withing chrome dev tools. Please advise if you can

```
app.post("/auth", function(req, response) {
  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err + "initial connection");
      console.log(config.server);
    } else {
      try {
        var request = new sql.Request();

        var body = req.body;

        //console.log(body);

        var Email = body.email;
        var Password = body.password;

        //console.log(email, password);

        try {
          request.input("email", sql.VarChar, Email);
          request.input("password", sql.VarChar, Password);
          request.query(
            "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = Email AND password = Password",

            function(error, results, fields) {
              if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.email = email;
                response.redirect("/home");
              } else if (results.length < 0) {
                response.send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
              }
            }
          );

          // response.send("Please enter email and Password!");
          // response.end();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          response.status(400);
          response.send(e);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        response.status(400);
        response.send(e);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     try {
          request.input("email", sql.VarChar, email);
          request.input("password", sql.VarChar, password);
          request.query(
            "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = 'email' AND password = 
           'password'",

            function(error, results, fields) {
              if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.email = email;
                response.redirect("/home");
              } else {
                response.send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
              }
              response.end();
            }
          );

          //response.send("Please enter email and Password!");
          //response.end();
```

The response ends `response.send("Please enter email and Password!");response.end();`, thus the handler once resolved gives that error.

Comment: Okay thankyou ! Any idea in why it is not redirecting the page?

Comment: No need for redirect at server end. You can do it in react using history `react-router`

Comment: how would this be done ? Is there any examples for things such as this ? Does redirecting in server end work as what I have makes logical sense if that is possible

Comment: response.redirect() should redirect . check the response in the network tab

Comment: fetch("/auth", {       it says this is where the error is cause in login page

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735496/redirect-after-a-fetch-post-call