# How do I redirect a user after login with fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, fetch

I'm making a node.js app with express and I'm trying to make a login form for my users,  I want to have a Javascript file with a fetch() call to make a POST request to my API to login the user, but I can't seem to redirect the user after a successful login, it stays on the same page, I can log the result from fetch but can't redirect.

Here's the server code (authentication is working fine, just the redirect isn't):

```
router.post('/users/login', login.none() , async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.cookie('access_token', 'Bearer ' + token, {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 8 * 3600000) // cookie will be removed after 8 hours
            })
            .redirect('/users/me')
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send()
    }
})
```

Here is my HTML + JS code (I know I don't need to have a function for this and can just use `action="/users/login"`, but I want to use javascript to handle errors with the login):

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<form id="loginform" action="/users/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    const loginForm = document.querySelector('#loginform');
    loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch('/users/login', { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(loginForm)} )
    })
</script>
```

Comment: `document.location` ?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is my HTML + JS code (I know I don't need to have a function for this and can just use action="/users/login", but I want to use javascript to handle errors with the login):

**TL;DR** Use `action` instead of `fetch()`. If you need help with the error handling part, post a new question about it.

Using `action` for form submission and JavaScript for error handling are not mutually exclusive. The problem here is that `fetch()` makes an AJAX request which returns the response as a value **directly in the current page**. It will not automatically redirect according to the response code. You can add some additional logic to do this, but why make this more complicated than necessary.

Instead add an `action` attribute to your `<form>`:

```
<form name="login" id="loginform" action="/users/login/" method="POST">
```

Then write JavaScript to do your error handling. Only call `preventDefault()` when there is an error to prevent the form submission. But allow normal submission when there is no errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my app, I'm not currently validating email/password (checking length, etc), I'm just veryfing if the credentials match with the users in the database, can I still handle that response with Javascript and form action? If so, do you know where I can learn more about this?

Comment: @GabrielLobo Verifying the username/password should be done on the backend. The frontend should know nothing about the database directly, so it shouldn't have access to the passwords anyway. (Aside: be sure the password are hashed in the database and not stored as plaintext.) In the case of invalid credentials, the `/users/login` route can return the form including an error message.

Comment: @GabrielLobo Where does the initial login form come from? How will a user navigate to it?

Comment: Yes, the verification is handled in the backend, here's what I'm trying to do: Submit form from front-end, verify email and pass in the backend, if credentials are valid, redirect the user to another page, else, stay on the same page but show an error on the form

Comment: @GabrielLobo You have at least two options here: 1. Use `action` as described in my answer which allows the browser to follow the redirect response returned by the Node.js backend. 2. Modify the Node.js backend to only acknowledge that the credentials are valid. It returns the cookie with the token but doesn't redirect. Then the frontend decides what to display next.

Comment: @GabrielLobo Which of these two you decide to use depends entirely on how you wish to design your webapp and depends on my previous question: where does the intial login form come from? If this form is served directly by your Node.js backend, then #1 is appropriate. The downside is that this tightly ties your frontend and backend together. On the other hand, #2 allows a much looser connection between the frontend and backend if you design the backend correctly as some kind of API, such as REST.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answers! I'll try to implement the second option next week, seeing that my back-end will be like an API. Happy hollidays!

Comment: @GabrielLobo In the case of an API, the backend should only return an auth token and not a redirect response. The front end is responsible for deciding what to display after recieving the response with the token. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 2):

You need to

- Set the `redirect` option on your `fetch()` to `manual`. If you don't, the default value is `follow`, and fetch will follow the redirect... meaning your response body andheaders will be that of the redirect target URL, not of your original `POST`.

Once you do that, `response.redirected` will be true if the request's response status is a 301/302 redirect. If `response.redirected` is true,

- set `window.location` to the redirect target. That should be `response.url` (and you should check `response.useFinalURL`, which, as you follow the redirect chain, should be `false` until you get a non-redirect status code.)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739894/467473) to the question [redirect after a fetch post call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39735496/467473).

Also:

- https://javascript.info/fetch-api#redirect
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

So your `submit` event handler should look something like:

```
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  fetch('/users/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'manual',
    body: new FormData(loginForm),
  }).then( res => {

    if ( response.redirected) {
       window.location.href = response.url;
       return;
    }

    // what do you do with a non-redirect?

  }).catch ( e => {

    // handle errors here

  });

})
```

Comment: This is not how manual redirects work. 

Basically manual redirects are used for web workers and nearly all previous data is zeroed when using this kinda of redirect.

respone.url in above case will be original fetch url

This is a great topic on how confusing manual redirect is: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/763

Answer (score 1):

**After login, if we get success response then we can use 4 different ways to redirect the page in javascript.**

**1. Redirection using (window.location.href) of Javascript**

```
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
```

**2. Redirection using replace() function**

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

**3. Redirection using window assign() function**

```
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
```

**4. Redirection using navigate function**

```
window.navigate("dashboard.html");
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I assume they mean replace and pushState.